# DisplayName on Model that use Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a code that look like this :

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "labelForName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
    public string name{ get; set; }
}
```

The problem is the attribute Display and Required have been added in the generated model class of Entity Framework. I know I can add functionality with Partial but how can I add attribute to a class that will be erase and updated with the ORM?

Comment: "but how can I add attribute to a class that will be erase and updated with the ORM?" Why would you want to do that?  Are you talking about changing the T4 template?  The autogenerated files are already part of your project, so you can easily just go in and change them (which would be pointless in the long run)

Comment: Because I have a multilangage wensite.

Comment: My question was why would you want to modify a file that you know will erase all your changes if you ever regenerate your files?  Do it in the partial or modify the T4 template.

Comment: The name property is synchronized with the Database. Every update erase the class generated and than recreate it. If I had manually the [Display] attribute, this attribute will be erased. Also, I cannot use Partial because Partial add methods and properties but not attribute to existing method.

Comment: Use a t4 template to modify the generated code pre build.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience, models from a database are seldom the same as being used in web pages. You always need some kind of change. Hence the usage of `ViewModel`s. Another upside is that all web pages that use your ViewModel won't break if the entity model is changed.

As for security, if you have a `public ActionResult Save(MyEntityModel model)` can lead to a security breach since the user may figure out how to post values to properties that shouldn't be changed (like `Role`, `Status`, `IsAdmin` or whatever).

Get yourself familiar with a mapper (like [automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com)) instead, and put the attributes on the ViewModel.

Comment: I have watched a screencast about AutoMapper and I see that it can do stuff methods but not adding attribute. Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unclear. Automapper just copies information from your entity to your ViewModel. You have to add the attributes to your viewmodel manually.

Comment: Yeah but because the AutoMapper just do that : OrderDto dto = Mapper.Map<Order, OrderDto>(order); I cannot add to OrderDTO some attribute on the method like the [Display(...)].

Comment: huh? Why not? It's the `OrderDTO` that is used in the web. Using validation attributes and display attributes on it makes perfect sense.

Comment: You are right, the documentation is very light... hard to get how the automapper library work :P I'll check more the screencast, all seem to be in it.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered a T4 Template to modify generated code.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

I tend to use T4 templates in combination with partial classes when dealing with generated code.

Comment: I am reading about it, doesn't want to make it too complex too. I may try to find an easier way.

Comment: There is a learning curve but its worth it. There is a powerful template used for MVC application on codeplex. Digg through there example im sure you will find some useful nuggets. http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC  If you want I could write you up and example of how to modify an attribute.