# Is it possible to add attributes to an existing class using .NET reflection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, .net-assembly, reflection.emit

I have the following class generated by EntityFramework,

```
public partial class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to add custom Attributes before using it or modifying the above class dynamically using reflection. Something like below,

```
public partial class Person
{
    [SomeCustomAttribute]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [SomeCustomAttribute]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to add custom attributes using reflection?

Comment: This is a better link for duplicate as the previous one doesn't really cover what peplamb wants. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889349/displayname-on-model-that-use-entity-framework

Comment: IE...the answer is really to either use a custom T4 template or make your EF classes just plain data access classes and put the attributes on a wrapper class for the UI.