# How to add custom property to entityType in designer

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, dsl, ef-model-first

I am doing model first development. 
Need a way to extend Entity Framework so that I can specıify displayName from the designer

Comment: What do you mean by display name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DisplayName on Model that use Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889349/displayname-on-model-that-use-entity-framework)

Comment: I think I will start from here blogs.msdn.com/b/craigl/archive/2010/01/14/extensibility-example-adding-custom-namespaces-in-your-code.aspx
The bad thing is I could not find the starter kit

Comment: [Yuliam Chandra] you can think of it as displayNameAttribute but it should be stored in edmx.

Comment: [Pragmateek] the question you have mentioned is not the same. The solution there is to use buddy classes for metadata. In my case adding those codes into code manually is not an option, storing additional data in edmx model is a requirement

Answer (score 0):

What I have done for now is I use custom metadataProvider and use the property I have added to the model. May there is some better way, but this worked for me.